# How to get information about the body of the procedure db2?

Tags: sql, db2-400

Is it possible to get information about the body of the procedure from the DB2 system tables: what tables used and which operations on them carried out?

I managed to find only :

```
SELECT *
FROM QSYS2.SYSROUTINEDEP
WHERE specific_name = 'proc_name'
AND object_type IN('TABLE','PROCEDURE')
```

Comment: A list from SYSROUTINEDEP is the best you can do.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the views system:

SYSFUNCS , SYSPARMS , SYSPROCS , SYSROUTINES, SYSROUTINEDEP, SYSPROGRAMSTAT

For détail: [IBM Site here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/db2/rbafzcatalogtbls.htm)